# How can I align text in a button

Tags: android, button, alignment

I want align the text in my button on the left, but not at all.

for clarifying, look at the red circle in the image.

[image]

Thanks.

(the first in the image is my result, the secondo what i'll want)

xml code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/activity_libretto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:text="Buongiorno!"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"

/>
```

Comment: so you want to align the text to left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="left|center_vertical"` in button's xml, and you can also add `android:paddingLeft="YOUR PADDING IN dp"`

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:gravity="left|center_vertical"` to your button.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>  <!-- this line -->
```